# How to unit test a 'v-show' property of a Vue Component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, vue.js, jestjs

When you have a button which shows based on a model, like so:

`<button v-show="title != ''">Add it</button>`

How would you test this? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I tried the following (using Jest, but runner/framework shouldn't matter):

```
describe('btn test', () => {
    it('should hide the add button initially', () => {

        // vm is set up here to be the vue component

        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button').style.display).toBe('none') // works

        // Update the input field (which has v-model="title")
        vm.$el.querySelectorAll('input').value = 'fd'

        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button').style.display).toBe('block') // is still 'none'

        // Update directly through vm prop
        vm.title = 'sheep'

        Vue.nextTick(() => {
            expect(vm.$el.querySelector('button').style.display).toBe('block') // is still 'none'
        })

    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by accident. Turns out the test needs a done parameter.

This does not work (notice the done param and callback)

```
it('should hide aap', () => {
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.aap').style.display).toBe('none')
    vm.showAap = true
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        // vm.showAap = false again
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.aap').style.display).toBe('')
    })
})
```

And this does work:

```
it('should hide aap', (done) => {
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.aap').style.display).toBe('none')
    vm.showAap = true
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.aap').style.display).toBe('')
        done()
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of all this `nextTick` magic, you could have simply done: `vm.setData({ showApp: true });`. This takes care of everything.

Answer (score 1):

changing the input's value via the DOM API will *not* update the data via v-model, because it does not trigger an input event, which v-model listens for.

So no data changed, and therefore, v-show is still `true`.

Solution, change the data on the vm.

```
vm.title = 'fd'
```

and use $nextTick as you did in the last line, because only then will the update be in the DOM

Comment: But i do that in my example above (line 14) but that doesn't do the trick